# Как исправить ошибку

Tags: грамотная-речь

Предложение: В то же время положительную оценку руководству организации, отвечающей за качество автомобильных дорог в нашем муниципальном образовании, дали 47 % опрошенных. По мониторингу этой сферы наш район находится на 31-м месте в области по оценке опрашиваемыми качества дорог. (по оценке опрашиваемыми качества дорог - как-то неправильно. Как исправить ошибку? Лично я даже смысл не понимаю. Подскажите.

Answer (score 1):

(если сохранить все возможные слова)

По данным мониторинга этой сферы, наш район находится на 31-м месте в области - так опрошенные оценили качество дорог.

Comment: Спасибо огромное за быстрый ответ.

Answer (score 0):

> По мониторингу этой сферы наш район находится на 31-м месте в области
>   по оценке опрашиваемыми качества дорог.

ВАРИАНТ: *По этому показателю наш район находится на 31-м месте в области.*